# Having different dependencies in grade builds?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a debug build and a release build of an android application however I need different dependencies for each, is this possible in Android Studio?

I have the section:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
}
```

and a section for the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'org.joda:joda-convert:1.4'
}
```

I want to remove the joda-convert dependancy if I am using the debug build as it results in "duplicate files in packaging of APK" error.

Any help greatly appreciated?

Comment: To put it basically, how can I remove a dependency when compiling in debug mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use

```
releaseCompile 'org.joda:joda-convert:1.4'
```

then joda-convert is only used for release

Comment: Dam it's really that easy! I assume debugCompile would work for just debug too? Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes - debugCompile would also work - you are welcome - if it solved your problem you might accept the answer - also you might want to have a look at https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP instead of joda-time

Comment: @ligi what if there's a third build type say ```staging```. How do we create a custom configuration for example, ```stagingImplementation``` ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android gradle documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-Android-Libraries-and-Multi-project-setup):

> The `compile` configuration is used to compile the main application.
>   Everything in it is added to the compilation classpath **and** also
>   packaged in the final APK. There are other possible configurations to
>   add dependencies to:
>
> - `compile`: main application
> - `androidTestCompile`: test application
> - `debugCompile`: debug Build Type
> - `releaseCompile`: release Build Type.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would to be removing Joda altogether, it wasn't really designed for Android in the first place it was really meant for Java only.

Try something like https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP which is very similar and shouldn't require you to change much code.

In answer to the original question however use releaseCompile and debugCompile to include or exclude what you need.

Comment: Thanks, ligi mentioned removing Joda too and it is something I am looking into.